# How to construct ConnectionStrings

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, entity-framework, config

Could you explain me how to construct correct `ConnectionStrings`? I mean that one you can find in `web.config` file in MVC project. I understand that if you want to add a new connection string you have to write `<add ... />` XML tag with parameters such as `name`, `connectionString` (it is the most interesting parameter for me) and `providerName` (perhaps some else?). What each parameter does and means? How to construct `connectionString` parameter? Where is the db engine indicated?

The questions above are only examples. I care about collecting the most amount of information about constructing `ConnectionStrings`.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ should give you examples for most every provider

Comment: don't forget to encrypt your connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to construct entity framework connection string just use as follows.It will help you..

```
string connectionString = new System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecb.Metadata = "res://*/Sample.csdl|res://*/Sample.ssdl|res://*/Sample.msl";
ecb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
ecb.ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString;
```

**UPDATED:**

The easiest way to get the connection string is using the Server explorer window in Visual Studio (View-->Server Explorer menu) and connect to the server from that window. Then you can see the connection string in the properties of the connected server (F4 with your connection selected).

If you create the database in SQL Server Management Studio, that database will be created in a server instance, so that, to deploy your application you'll have to make a backup of the database and deploy it in the deployment SQL Server. Alternatively, you can use a data file using SQL Server Express (localDB in SQL Server 2012), that will be easily distributed with your app.

I.e. if it's an ASP.NET app, there's an App_Datafolder. If you right click it you can add a new element, which can be a SQL Server Database. This file will be on that folder, will work with SQL Express, and will be easy to deploy. You need SQL Express installed on your machine.

Comment: No, I don't mean constructing dynamic connection strings. I would like to create static connection string in `web.config` file, but I don't understand connection strings I found in the network.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from NET 2.0 you have at your disposal a class named [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

Its purpose is to help building dynamically the connection string. But the various properties available explain in great detail the functionality underlying to each possible setting

The SqlConnectionStringBuilder class is derived by a base class named [DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) and this allows all the ADO.NET provider to implement their own version of this class. In the link provided  there are the references relative to other ADO.NET providers